# How to make a 2D Camera follow script only go in one direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a camera follow script and I want to make it only go in one direction and also for some reason i made it start when the target is in the middle of the screen and then the camera pushes so the player is at the edge

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StartFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform follow;
    public Transform targetObject;
    private Vector3 initalOffset;
    private Vector3 cameraPosition;
    private bool test;
    void Start()
    {
        initalOffset = follow.position - targetObject.position;
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (test == true)
        {
            cameraPosition = targetObject.position + initalOffset;
            follow.position = cameraPosition;
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        test = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "I want to make it only go in one direction"? Make *what* go one direction? Which direction?

Comment: I only want it to move along the x axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asher. You could try to use this

```
private void MoveCamera()
{
    // Get the current position
    Vector3 newPosition = camera.transform.position;
    // Only modifies the x axis
    newPosition.x = target.position.x;

    transform.position = newPosition;
}
```

Or if you wanted the camera to move smoothly try to take a look at [Vector3.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) or any other interpolation function

Here is an example of [Vector3.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)

```
private void MoveCamera()
{
    // Get the current position
    Vector3 newPosition = camera.transform.position;
    // Only modifies the x axis
    newPosition.x = target.position.x;

    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Where the `speed` variable is affecting the speed of the camera smoothing

Also, I would highly suggest you use `FixedUpadte` or `LateUpdate` to update your camera to avoid any nasty jittery effect

Comment: To make it work on the y axis would I switch the x for a y

Comment: @AsherHeller just add `newPosition.y = target.position.y;` and you should be good

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to go to the right:

```cs
if(test && (targetObject.position + initalOffset).x > cameraPosition.x) {
        ...
}
```